# How make "color isolation" effect like in photoshop with java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I would like to know how to **isolate** a certain **color** in an image and set the rest to gray using java.

So far I managed to do so, but in a **hardcode** way by looping through all the **pixels** of the image and then checking the **RGB** values.
I am using **BufferedImage** to load the image and the **Color** class to deal with RGB values.

The **isColorRed** checks if the color is red or not.

```
private static boolean isColorRed(Color color) {
    int red = color.getRed();
    int green = color.getGreen();
    int blue = color.getBlue();

    return ((red >= 70 && red <= 255) && (green >= 0 && green <= 80) && (blue >= 0 && blue <= 80));
}
```

The **isolateColor** method is responsible to set all pixels to grey except for the red ones.

```
private static void isolateColor(BufferedImage image) {

    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {

            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));

            if (!isColorRed(c)) {
                int red = (int) (c.getRed() * 0.3);
                int green = (int) (c.getGreen() * 0.587);
                int blue = (int) (c.getBlue() * 0.114);

                int gray = red + green + blue;

                Color newColor = new Color(gray, gray, gray);
                image.setRGB(x, y, newColor.getRGB());
            } else {
                Color newColor = new Color(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue());
                image.setRGB(x, y, newColor.getRGB());
            }

        }
    }

    File file;
    try {
        file = new File("src/grey.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The original image :

[image]

After the treatment :

[image]

Is there any API **built-in** or **external** that can isolate **one color or more** in a single image

Comment: you need to use multiple calls to do this. do not expect this to be as trivial as calling a single function. -- you need to convert to a suitable color space (HSV/HSL), then change the saturation of every pixel according to its hue (leave red ones, desaturate others), and convert back for storage/display. this may involve a "mask" (binary image), or you can modulate the amount of desaturation according to *how red* a pixel is (smooth fade, not binary decision). -- you really should use OpenCV for that. don't touch pixels yourself. that's slow and error-prone.